# How to create a mutable nested iterator?

Tags: rust

I want to compare each element of an array with each other element of the same array, and if certain conditions are met, the properties of both elements need to be updated.
In any other programming language of my knowledge I would achieve this with two nested iterators.

In Rust the nested usage of "iter_mut" creates the error "cannot borrow `balls` as mutable more than once at a time".

This is my "balls" example:

```
struct Ball {
    pub x: f64,
    pub y: f64,
}

let mut balls: Vec<Ball> = vec![Ball {x: 10.0, y:10.0}, Ball {x: 10.0, y:10.0}];

for ball in balls.iter_mut() {
    for ball2 in balls.iter_mut() { //this second iterator raises the error

        if ball.x == ball2.x { //any test
            ball.x = 0.5; //any value change
            ball2.x = 0.5;//any value change
        }

    }
}
```

What is the best way to achive this in Rust?

Comment: I would consider using an interior mutable type

Comment: @DanielA.White For such simple cases it is probably better to just use indices.

Comment: Please do not "Rust" in the title. We can already see it in the tags.

Comment: ok - sorry - I tought you mind the style with the colon...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best way to achive this in Rust?

The easiest is to iterate using indexes:

```
for i in 0..balls.len() {
    for j in 0..balls.len() {
        if balls[i].x == balls[j].x {
            balls[i].x = 0.5;
            balls[j].x = 0.5;
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d9b3efc1d3b7d5a16c6cfc446ae9b72b)

Comment: Also, we can speed things up by not comparing things that have already been compared:

`for j in (i + 1)..balls.len()`

Comment: Excellent. I am new to Rust, but this is something I should have been able to figure out by myself.

Comment: And thanks to Yoric too for your optimization!

Comment: @Kez Don't fret about it, all of us sometimes try so hard to do things the "right" way, or the sophisticated-fp way, that we forget about a ridiculously simple approach to the problem. Have fun with Rust!

Comment: Thanks for the "cheer up". I barely started working my way through the book. And this phyiscs ball is my learning tutorial.